# How not to dismiss keyboard in iPad even if the user presses the dismiss button on the right bottom?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, keyboard-events, dismiss

On one of my view controllers on iPad, I don't want the user to dismiss the keyboard even if the user presses the dismiss button on the right bottom of the keyboard. I want this because there's nothing else on the view that he can do without the keyboard and the button below the textfields, and the view looks empty without the keyboard.

I've tried listening to keyboardWillHide notification and making one of my text fields the first responder on the callback method but it didn't work. I've tried returning NO from textFieldShouldReturn or textFieldShouldEndEditing methods but they don't produce the behavior I want, either.

Below is the screenshot of a scratch view. Do you have any other ideas?[image]

Comment: Have you tried using canResignFirstResponder:?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to return NO in UITextField delegate's - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField ?

Comment: Yes I did. But when I do so, the user can't go from one text field to the other. That's what I was meaning to say in this sentence above "I've tried returning NO from textFieldShouldReturn or textFieldShouldEndEditing methods but they don't produce the behavior I want, either.". Thx though :)